# Hive is automatically rounding off the scale 18 to scale 15 in Decimal even after specifying the Decimal(38,18)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

### Query

```
select CAST((123456789876567898/1000000000000000000) as decimal(38,18));
```

Result

```
0.123456789876568
```

Expected result

```
0.123456789876567898
```

Can some one please help on this?

Comment: hive and spark are two different products

Comment: What do you expect to achieve by casting the **result** of the division operation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert them separately before converting the result of division.

Below SQL will give you expected result.

```
select CAST((
cast(123456789876567898 as decimal(38,18))/
cast(1000000000000000000 as decimal(38,18))) as decimal(38,18));
```

[image: result]

**Reason** - When you calculate a/b, hive calculate and generate result in double and when you try to cast it to decimal(38,18), it show you truncated value.
When you explicitly convert them to decimal, hive calculate everything in decimal and produce result in decimal. When you cast result to decimal again, no data loss happens.

Comment: The precision of a double (15-17 digits) is defined by the IEEE standard, i.e. its not the result of truncation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.

Comment: Hive rules for precision and scale of the result when using `Decimal`'s are stated in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27362075/Hive_Decimal_Precision_Scale_Support.pdf . Still, good answer!

Comment: i understand the logic when hive divide decimal/decimal. But how about double/double? As far as i know hive consider everything as double if you dont explicitly mention/cast. so double/double will result a double.

Comment: If the length of the digit exceeds 18 precisions it is rounding off to 15 or 16 scale
select CAST((
cast(12345678987656789898 as decimal(38,18))/
cast(1000000000000000000 as decimal(38,18))) as decimal(38,18));

Actual result : 12.34567898765679

expected result : 12.345678987656789898


Can you please suggest on this

Comment: Precision of your expected result `12.345678987656789898` is 19.

Comment: But i can see your issue. Hive is not working with calculation over decimal(38,18) and throwing null when i am trying to cast to decimal(38,20) before calculation. it may be a limitation.